# How to place the hotspot on the 3d models?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, augmented-reality, aframe

I have a question as I attempt to combine two codes. I'm trying to place the hotspot elements on each 3d model when I click on the 'next 3d model'. The hotspots are kind particular information of each model. I would like to make it change as I swap the models. I tried to combine them by following the array with the models' code.

Any idea how to make it work? Tips? Thank you in advance =)

**Here is the HTML code**

'''

```
<div id="nextbutton" style="display: none; z-index: 10">
  <h2>Next 3D Model</h2>
</div>

<!-- Hotspot Project -->

<div id="recenterButtonContainer" class="hidden">
  <img src="./assets/images/recenter.png">
</div>

<div id="container" class="collapsed">
  <div class="outer">
     <div id="closeButton" onclick="hideAll()">Close</div>
  </div>
<div class="outer" id="contents"></div>
  <!--<div class="outer">Contents go here</div>-->
</div>

<a-scene
  next-button
  recenter-button
  xrextras-gesture-detector
  xrextras-almost-there
  xrextras-loading
  xrextras-runtime-error
  renderer="colorManagement: true"
  xrweb>

  <!-- We can define assets here to be loaded when A-Frame initializes -->
  <a-assets>
    <a-asset-item id="humanModel" src="assets/models/human-hand.glb"></a-asset-item>
    <a-asset-item id="grassModel" src="assets/models/grass-hand.glb"></a-asset-item>
    <a-asset-item id="dirtyModel" src="assets/models/dirty-hand.glb"></a-asset-item>
    <a-mixin id="hotspot-text" text="font: exo2bold; width: 5" geometry="primitive: plane; width: 1.6; height: 0.4" material="color: black;" position="0 0.5 0"></a-mixin>
    <a-mixin id="hotspot-target" geometry="primitive: octahedron; radius: 0.2;" material="flatShading: true; color: rgb(255, 0, 161)"></a-mixin>
  </a-assets>

  <!-- The raycaster will emit mouse events on scene objects specified with the cantap class -->
  <a-camera
    id="camera"
    position="0 4 6"
    raycaster="objects: .cantap"
    cursor="fuse: false; rayOrigin: mouse;">
  </a-camera>

  <a-entity
    light="
      type: directional;
      intensity: 0.8;
      castShadow: true;
      shadowMapHeight:2048;
      shadowMapWidth:2048;
      shadowCameraTop: 10;
      target: #model;"
    xrextras-attach="target: model; offset: 1 15 3;"
    shadow>
  </a-entity>

  <a-light type="ambient" intensity="0.7"></a-light>

<a-entity 
    id="model"
    gltf-model="#humanModel" 
    class="cantap" 
    xrextras-hold-drag
    xrextras-two-finger-rotate 
    xrextras-pinch-scale
    scale="50 50 50" 
    shadow="receive: false">

<!--Hotspot #1-->
    <a-entity id="hotspot1" mixin="hotspot-target" position="-0.515 0.505 0.969" rotation="0 0 0" scale="0.5 0.5 0.5" look-at="#camera" class="cantap" tap-hotspot>
      <a-text id="hotspot1-child" value="Hotspot 1" align="center" mixin="hotspot-text" visible="false" tap-close></a-text>
    </a-entity>

  </a-entity>

<a-entity 
    id="model"
    gltf-model="#grassModel" 
    class="cantap" 
    xrextras-hold-drag
    xrextras-two-finger-rotate 
    xrextras-pinch-scale
    scale="50 50 50" 
    shadow="receive: false">

<!--Hotspot #2-->
    <a-entity id="hotspot2" mixin="hotspot-target" position="0.857 0.815 0.078" rotation="0 0 0" scale="0.5 0.5 0.5" look-at="#camera" class="cantap" tap-hotspot>
      <a-text id="hotspot2-child" value="Hotspot 2" align="center" mixin="hotspot-text" visible="false" tap-close></a-text>
    </a-entity>

  </a-entity>

    <a-entity 
    id="model"
    gltf-model="#dirtyModel" 
    class="cantap" 
    xrextras-hold-drag
    xrextras-two-finger-rotate 
    xrextras-pinch-scale
    scale="50 50 50" 
    shadow="receive: false">

<!--Hotspot #3-->
    <a-entity id="hotspot3" mixin="hotspot-target" position="0.167 0.953 -0.728" rotation="0 0 0" scale="0.5 0.5 0.5" look-at="#camera" class="cantap" tap-hotspot>
      <a-text id="hotspot3-child" value="Hotspot 3" align="center" mixin="hotspot-text" visible="false" tap-close></a-text>
    </a-entity>

  </a-entity>
  
  <a-plane
    id="ground" 
    rotation="-90 0 0" 
    width="1000" 
    height="1000" 
    material="shader: shadow" 
    shadow>
  </a-plane>
</a-scene> '''
```

**Here is the Javascript file I'm trying to code the swap models and hotspots**
'''

```
const nextButtonComponent = () => ({
  init() {
    const modelList = ['humanModel', 'grassModel', 'dirtyModel']
    const model = document.getElementById('model')
    const hotspotList = ['hotspot1', 'hotspot2', 'hotspot3']
    const hotspot = document.getElementById('hotspot-target')
    const nextButton = document.getElementById('nextbutton')
    nextButton.style.display = 'block'

    let idx = 1  // Start with the 2nd model as 1st is already in the scene on page load
    const nextModel = () => {
      // Need to remove gltf-component first due to AFrame regression: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/4341
      model.removeAttribute('gltf-model')
      // Switch to next model in the list
      model.setAttribute('gltf-model', `#${modelList[idx]}`)

      idx = (idx + 1) % modelList.length
    }
    nextButton.onclick = nextModel

    const inx = 1
    const nextHotspot = () => {
      // Need to remove gltf-component first due to AFrame regression: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/4341
      hotspot.removeAttribute('hotspot-target')
      // Switch to next model in the list
      hotspot.setAttribute('hotspot-target', `#${nextHotspot[idx]}`)

      idx = (idx + 1) % hotspotList.length
    }

    nextButton.onclick = nextModel  // Switch to the next model when the button is pressed.
  },
})
export {nextButtonComponent} '''
```

Comment: A tip: use purely three.js for building 3D canvases, even if it needs more time. A-frame is slower fps, requires more RAM usage, and heats the laptops of the users like a lot! however it is way faster to develop with a-frame than three.js but a-frame cannot scale.

Comment: I recommend sharing simple code with https://glitch.com/~aframe it will be much easier to help you.

Comment: Also not true that A-Frame has perf overhead or doesn’t scale. Out of scope here. happy to answer any questions address concerns on Slack / Discord https://aframe.io/community/